# Mysql Wildcard in field

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wildcard

I have a mysql database and my table is :

```
Name      | passcode
----------------------
hi*       | 1111
----------------------
j?n       | 2222
```

i want this query has a result like this :

```
Select * from Users Where Name='hiiiiiiiiiiii'
```

The Query result is my first row and * and ? works like a wildcard but i use it in my database field

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking.  Can you be more specific, and show some code that doesn't give the result you thought it would?

Comment: @joelgoldstick i have a filed in my sql like the above example i want Select * from Users Where Name='hiiiiiiiiiiii' or Select * from Users Where Name='hiii' result return the first row because * means zero or more character in wildcard but i dont want use LIKE command in mysql .

Comment: You have it backwards.  You can't use wildcards in your Name

Comment: @joelgoldstick what can i do ? i want get string like this in mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30758814/3612353

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to put the wildcard in the actual value stored in the database field. To solve this example you would need to concat the wild card in your query...

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE 'hiiiiii' LIKE CONCAT('%',`Name`,'%')
```

Comment: if i want select somthing like : " Sala*m " , what can i do ? SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE 'salaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaam' LIKE CONCAT('%',`Name`,'%')   doesnt work

Comment: Your probably going to have to look into a regex to achieve this. You can design a test which will look for a pattern that starts with "Sal" and then accepts any number of "a"s and finishes in an "m". However if your patterns are inconsistent then this is not going to be manageable as you will need a regex for every case

Comment: how can i use regexp to recognize that string ?

Comment: You will have to look into it. There is a lot of info about it on SO. I think you probably need to change your design though unless the strings are limited and in a consistent format you wont be able to design a regex for every possible case

Answer (score 0):

You can tyr regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'hiiiiii'                REGEXP Name; -- hi*
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'jn'                     REGEXP Name; -- j?n
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'salaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaam' REGEXP Name; -- Sala*m
```

but you should be careful, because:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'say hiiii to all!' REGEXP Name; -- hi*
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'Jn'                REGEXP Name; -- j?n
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'n'                 REGEXP Name; -- j?n
```

that's why you should specify more strict pattern at field name...

And i suppose that it will be not best solution in performance...